# How can normal sports be modified for playing in micro-gravity conditions?

Tags: microgravity, reduced-gravity-sports

What new equipment would we use to play sports such as football, basket ball, etc., in micro-gravity?

What changes would we make to the games above?

Also, are there any scholarly articles or proper research done on sports in space?

Comment: All these sports are impossible in microgravity, space travelers will need to invent new ones. I don't think this is answerable, or on-topic.